# Oracle, substring from right then pad left, odd behavior

Tags: oracle, substr

Ok, so i have an ASN_NO, it can be 30 chars.

I'm required to take the 10 RIGHT most characters of it. No problem.

```
SUBSTR(ASN_NO,-10, 10) -- this works fine
```

But sometimes the ASN_NO can be less than 10 characters, and in that case i need to pad it with left zeros.

```
LPAD(ASN_NO,10,'0') -- this works when less than 10 characters, except when having an ASN_NO greater it substrings from the left
```

So then if i try to use them in conjuction

```
LPAD(SUBSTR(ASN_NO,-10, 10),10,'0') -- this gives me a null result when less than 10 but i dont understand why?
```

So then i came up with this:

```
LPAD(SUBSTR(ASN_NO, CASE WHEN LENGTH(SI.ASN_NO) >= 10 THEN -10 ELSE -LENGTH(ASN_NO) END, 10),10,'0')
```

This last statement using length in conjunction with substring when less that 10 works...but am i overworking this/over thinking this? Anyone know whats going on an a cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nvl` function, will be something like:

```
lpad(nvl(SUBSTR(ASN_NO,-10),asn_no),10,'0')
```

In case that length is lower than 10 then `SUBSTR(ASN_NO,-10)` return null, so in this case nvl function will return the entire string.

As a note, you don't need to specify third parameter to get last 10 chars, substr(ASN_NO,-10) should be enough.

Comment: Ok, this and Martin's answer both works well, im not sure which way is more elegant, but based on my question, this answers my confusion about what was going on better pertaining the nulls, so is probably the more precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you ask for the last 10 characters of a string which has less than 10 characters you get NULL.

You need to LPAD first and then SUBSTR.

Also the second parameter (LENGTH) to SUBSTR is obsolete when you want to get all characters up to the end.

Comment: But the problem is the LPAD function substrings itself from the left. So lets say i have the string '123456789012'. After the LPAD(10), it will be '1234567890' instead of '3456789012' before it makes it to the SUBSTR function, and by then SUBSTR is pointless because it already substrings it down to 10.

Comment: I see. Would it be an option to LPAD to the max string lenght you expect?

Comment: I guess ya, and then substr it, that would work better than my crazy way. I'm going to try Aramillos next too, and figure out what i think seems more elegant. I think these may both be answers.

Comment: They are not equivalent. In my suggestion you always get 10 characters possibly left-padded with zeros, in aramillos suggestion you may end up with a string with less than 10 characters. It depends on what you need.

Comment: Sorry Martin, not sure i follow you, he has an outer LPAD which still fixes that and makes it always 10. I test both your answers and they worked the same.

Comment: Either way i appreciate both of you guys help as it did solve the problem.